# Interop not creating coclass

Tags: c#, com, interop, components, coclass

I have a legacy COM component which I need wrap and use in .NET code. When I used the tlbimp to create the RCW for the component just one interface had a coclass created to which I was able to make a call.
Rest five or so interface does not have a coclass. If I look up in ildasm on the interop there are just interfaces without coclass.

How do I make this work to be able to call all methods on the component.
Is there a way I can add coclass code myself in and expect the implementation to work.

Comment: This is quite normal, a coclass typically implements more than one interface.  Just like the List class implements IList and ICollection and IEnumerable etc.  It just takes a simple cast in C# to obtain a reference to the other interfaces.  Like `var itf2 = (ISomeOtherInterface)obj;`   Or it might be returned by one of the methods.

Comment: @Hans Thanks. You mean one of the coclasses might have the implementation. I did try casting existing coclass which fails with an error on casting.